# Opening a csv file that's given in a function

Tags: python

I'm trying to open a file that is given when the function is ran and the name of the file is from the function.

Here's my current code:

```
import csv

def a_test(filename):
    with open(filename) as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        for row in reader:
                print(row)
```

When I run this and type `a_test(media-song.csv)` (media-song.csv being a file in the same directory), I get this error:

```
NameError: name 'media' is not defined
```

Comment: you need to pass `media-song.csv` as a string. So: `a_test("media-song.csv")`

Comment: Rename the file by removing the **-** from the name. Apparently, python is treating **media** and **song** as operands to the subtraction **-** operation. Example name could be **MediaSong.csv**.

Comment: @eapetcho technically, it's trying to do `a - b.attr`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`a_test('media-song.csv')`. Argument should be a string